# Making Folders on SDcard in android

Tags: android, java-io

I am making an Android App for that i need to create folders on storage disk card.
My Main Activity class:
I have added three buttons and each click is to write a folder.
My program is being executed but Toast Message is "Directory is not Created."
I checked my storage disk card,and Its there, I also added user permissions in manifest.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final boolean isSDWritable = SDcard.isExternalStorageWritable();
    buttonDownlaod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_directoryDownload);
    buttonPictures = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_directoryPictures);
    buttonMovies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_directoryMovies);
    buttonDownlaod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isSDWritable) {
                getStorageDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "MyDownlaods");
            }
        }
    });
    buttonMovies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isSDWritable) {
                getStorageDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES, "MyMovies");
            }
        }
    });
    buttonPictures.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isSDWritable) {
                getStorageDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "MyPictures");
            }
        }
    });
}

public File getStorageDir(String inBuiltDir, String folderName) {
    String inBuiltdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(inBuiltDir, folderName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Directory is not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Name" + folderName + "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return file;
}

} // Update code formatting
```

Can anyone help that whats wrong in the code which is why Directory is not Created.

Comment: Do you have the permission to write to external storage declared in the manifest file??

Comment: Yes i did have permission. I declared in manifest file..

Comment: Code is working fine now. Just implemented getExternalFilesDir() instead of getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: ah yes with you new android OS specs it forces you to create files in the location tagged for storing application specific files

Answer (score 0):

I think you cann't create folders in these porticular directories.Try other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+folderName+"/");
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: replaced with your code, no change. Message is still "Directory is not created"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I want to create sample folder on SD card

```
File recordingDirectory = new File("/sdcard/sample/");
if (!recordingDirectory.exists()) {
    recordingDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```